# Play! 2.4 - Implicit Reads for ScalaJson w/ Generic Types

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.4

Using Play 2.4 ScalaWS. I've defined a method that takes a type manifest `T` and performs a `GET` request to an external API. The problem is that it won't compile because there isn't an implicit `Reads` for parsing JSON.

Here's the code:

```
def myGet[T](path: String)(implicit m: Manifest[T]): Future[Either[model.MyError,T]]  = {
    val url = MY_HOST+"/"+path
    ws
      .url(url)
      .withHeaders(myHeaders: _*)
      .get()
      .map { response =>
        try {
          Right(response.json.as[T])
        } catch {
          // check if this response was an error
          Left(response.json.as[model.MyError])
        }
      }

  }
```

The compilation error is specifically:

```
Compilation error[No Json deserializer found for type T. Try to implement an implicit Reads or Format for this type.]
```

I'm not sure of the simplest way to do this. Thanks for your help.

### Edit

I also tried `(implicit m: Manifest[T], reads: Reads[T])` with no luck.

Comment: It seems like the `Manifest[T]` would not be necessary, though it's hard to tell from the context. Just a thought.

Comment: Here's how I use it in an oversimplified form: `def fetchProfile = myGet[UserProfile]("/user")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out using `(implicit m: Manifest[T], readsT: Reads[T])` and having the `Reads` be an implicit parameter was the correct way of doing this. I had to run `sbt clean` since something was improperly cached in the incremental compiler.

It now works just fine.